# Sorting fetched results controller data, using two properties, using sort descriptors

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a simple reminder app for plants. I'm trying to sort the data that I get via Core Data's `NSFetchedResultsController`. My problem is: the data that I'm trying to sort relies on the manipulation of 2 properties.

I have a `Plant` object with these properties: `waterCycle` and `lastWater`.

`waterCycle` is the number (`Double`) of days in-between that plant requires water and `lastWater` is the date (`NSDate`) when the plant was last watered. I have a function that calculates, if the plant is due, how many days late since it required water. (*i.e. Needed water 3 days ago!*)

After some research, I believe I cannot sort based on computed properties or do anything too funky with fetch requests. I'm trying to achieve this with `NSFetchRequest` and `NSSortDescriptor` but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions are welcome on how to tackle this challenge.

One alternative I had in mind was that I could keep this data within the object record, but that would imply that the app would need to recompute and save all objects each day in order only to bump that late day number which is pretty cumbersome in my opinion.

Here's some code, do not hesitate to ask for more info or code. Thanks!

---

**NSFetchedResultsController**

```
private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Plant", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    // this should sort the list so plant that needs water are on top
    let waterCycleSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "waterCycle", ascending: true)
    let lastWaterSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastWater", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [waterCycleSortDescriptor, lastWaterSortDescriptor]

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                               managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!,
                                                               sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: PlantRepository.getCacheName())
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

---

I calculate the number of late days with a function similar to this (simplified for post):

```
static func getLateDays(lastWater: NSDate, waterCycle: Double) -> Int {
    // add waterCycle days to lastWater
    let toDate = lastWater.dateByAddingTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(60*60*24*waterCycle))
    // calc late days after due date
    let lateDays = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: toDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
    return lateDays.day
}
```

---

Comment: How big is your dataset?  You are correct, you can't sort on computed properties.  One approach would be to load the whole set of `Plant`s and then filter and sort the array in memory.

Comment: It depends on the user but ultimately the dataset could get quite bit including child objects and even data (pictures). I had thought of that but that would require extra manipulation outside of the NSFetchedResultsController. I guess that'd be possible though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've struggled with looking for ways to sort `NSFetchedResultsController` from a computed property/transient attribute as well and after attempting several hacks found no good option.

If I was tacking this specific problem, I would add an attribute that holds the target date for the plant to be watered, and use this for sorting.

You won't need to calculate this every day, but instead updated this only when the user updates the value for `lastWater` - this will be accurate for making sure that results are ordered, and in the view you can calculate on the fly how many days ahead (or behind) you are for the watering schedule.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I hadn't thought of that! That's the closest to a solution I have so far! I'll keep on digging some more but I could end up trying this instead! Thanks so much!